# Join on two different Objects: Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a trouble on Joining a `IObjectSet<T>` with a `IEnumerable<int>` , where T has a type int as a property. I just can join the objects of that kind. How ever if I convert IObjectSet to List I can join them. Any ideas on reason why this happens? ANy one experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to bring the collection in memory. You can't do a join across the database and a collection in memory, the EF query provider will get mad at you.